# Laravel Inertia Vue 3 terminable middleware

Tags: laravel, vue.js, middleware, inertiajs

I implemented a terminable middleware in a Laravel application with Inertia and Vue 3 in SSR mode.
The handle method is executed but not the terminate method. I think this is due to the SSR nature of the application, however can someone explain to me clearly why the terminate method is not executing and is there a way to execute this method?

```
class LastActivityMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        //this code is executed
        if (auth()->check()) { 
            $user = auth()->user();
            $user->last_activity = now();
            $user->save();
        }
        // dd('handle');
        return $response;
    }

    public function terminate(Request $request, Response $response): void 
    {
        dd('terminate'); //this is not executed
    }
}
```